# ServiceNotFoundException Unable to resolve service “Router” to a factory Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new to Zend Framework. When I run the program I am getting the following exception:

[image: Error Image]

I have tried all solutions from stack overflow and other resources and other means. Please help me guys.

**config/modules.config.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'Zend\ServiceManager\Di',
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
    'Zend\Mvc\Console',
    'Zend\Log',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\db',
    'Zend\Cache',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'Application',
    'Album'
];

?>
```

Comment: Please give more information about your setup

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json` as in which versions of the libraries are you using and your `index.php` as well so we know how you create the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the setup was/is quite similar to that of Zend Framework 3. As I'm using that and thus have that code handy, I'll show you that setup.

---

The example you've given, of your `modules.config.php` file does not match the error message you've screenshot(ted?) for us.

If a module, requested via the `modules.config.php` file, cannot be loaded you get another error, namely:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (DEMO\NOT\FOUND\MODULE) could not be initialized. in C:\xampp\htdocs\DEMO_PROJECT\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php on line 203

---

#### Whoops

*Kwido correctly pointed out in the comments below that the remainder of this answer has nothing to do for the OP's issue. Leaving it here in case someone else finds it handy.*

---

What I think you're doing is trying to get the `Router` class from somewhere (something along these lines: `$serviceLocator->get(Router::class)`), based on the fact that there is a `zendframework/zend-router` folder in your vendor folder and a `Zend\Router` namespace which floats around.

However, within the `zend-router` module, you'll find a `ConfigProvider` class (`vendor/zendframework/zend-router/src/ConfigProvider.php`). Here you'll find this function, which returns configuration:

```
/**
 * Provide default container dependency configuration.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getDependencyConfig()
{
    return [
        'aliases' => [
            'HttpRouter' => Http\TreeRouteStack::class,
            'router' => RouteStackInterface::class,
            'Router' => RouteStackInterface::class,
            'RoutePluginManager' => RoutePluginManager::class,
        ],
        'factories' => [
            Http\TreeRouteStack::class => Http\HttpRouterFactory::class,
            RoutePluginManager::class => RoutePluginManagerFactory::class,
            RouteStackInterface::class => RouterFactory::class,
        ],
    ];
}
```

This method gets initialized `On bootstrap` (gain more insight into events [here](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Website_Operation/Events__amp__Application_s_Life_Cycle.html)).

The lines below allow you to do something like `$this->getServiceManager()->get('Router')` (in ZF2) or `$container->get('Router')` (in ZF3):

```
'router' => RouteStackInterface::class,
'Router' => RouteStackInterface::class,
```

However, you cannot do `$serviceLocator->get(Router::class)`! This is because it has only been registered as an alias! You must get it by the strings `router` or `Router`.

Comment: Maybe you should read the stacktrace and you'll notice that the application is not trying to load the router by FQCN but by a string.

Comment: Uh yea indeed. Read over that part. Still, the first bit of my answer stands, I'll just leave it all here in case it helps others.